# Export gridView with icon to outlook body

Tags: c#, winforms, outlook, devexpress

This is my gridView

[image]

This is my code to export gridview to outlook

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        string str;
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            gridView2.ExportToHtml(ms);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
            str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            ms.Close();
        }
        oMsg.To = "test@test.com";
        oMsg.Subject = "Test: ";
        oMsg.BodyFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
        oMsg.Display(false); 

        oMsg.HTMLBody = "Test" + str +  oMsg.HTMLBody;
```

the code work fine but the icons does not show up on outlook
[image]

The icons is builtin in gridview
How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance .
Update:I have add IconSet using ColumnView.FormatRules Property in Designer
[ColumnView.FormatRules](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.FormatRules)

[image: FormatRules Property in Designer]

Comment: How are the icons drawn? Via CustomDrawCell event?

Comment: I have update my question please review it

Comment: Ok, I see… You're trying two different items to the same cell. Split those into two seperate cells (columns).